# Top n products sold for each merchant in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I had read the dplyr documentation and still cannot understand group_by method well. I am trying to find the top 3 products (product_id) sold by each merchant (merchant_id). The code I tried was the following

```
tmp <- orders %>%
         group_by(product_id, merchant_id) %>%
         summarize(count = n()) %>% 
         top_n(3, wt = count) %>%
         arrange(desc(count))
```

Should the merchant have sold less than 3 unique products, I would like them to show corresponding number of products.

INPUT

```
order_id | product_id | merchant_id |
---------|------------|-------------|
23409    |  131883    |   597       |
23683    |  131885    |   597       |
25325    |  131885    |   597       |
25390    |  131885    |   597       |
25410    |  131888    |   597       |
25325    |  223783    |   613       |
28932    |  223815    |   613       |
38197    |  298483    |   613       |
48728    |  298483    |   613       |
```

If I were to find the top 3 products for each product, I expect the output to be (count numbers don't match in the example because I would have to create MANY rows but the format will be as such)

OUTPUT

```
count    | product_id | merchant_id |
---------|------------|-------------|
    5    |  131883    |   597       |
    3    |  131885    |   597       |
    2    |  131888    |   597       |
    4    |  223783    |   613       |
    2    |  223815    |   613       |
    1    |  298483    |   613       |
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your need to modify your code just a little bit. You want to do the `top_n` on the data grouped by `merchant_id`, not on the data grouped by `(product_id, merchant_id)`, so you should ungroup before grouping again.
Also, if you want `arrange` to sort counts within groups of `merchant_id`, you should specifiy it also.

```
orders %>%
group_by(product_id, merchant_id) %>%
summarize(count = n()) %>% 
ungroup() %>% 
group_by(merchant_id) %>%
top_n(3, wt = count) %>% 
arrange(merchant_id,desc(count))
```

This returns:

```
product_id merchant_id count
       <int>       <int> <int>
1     131885         597     3
2     131883         597     1
3     131888         597     1
4     298483         613     2
5     223783         613     1
6     223815         613     1
```

Also, note that if there are ties, `top_n` can return more than n values.